# Magento 2.3.X Admin Panel Category storeview switcher not working after upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have upgraded my Magento version from 2.1.9 to 2.3.0 using script.now every thing works fine except category.
when i select category with "All store view" its editable but when i switch store it redirect me to "Default Category"

[ScreenVideo](https://www.screencast.com/t/SUTb7Miij)

Comment: Have you check log files?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya yes checked. nothing found in log, no error in page